# How to control the inferred type for bound variables in pattern matching in the presence of higher-kinded types

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, abstract-data-type, algebraic-data-types, higher-kinded-types

(this is based on the article at http://bertails.org/2015/02/15/abstract-algebraic-data-type)

First, I am defining an abstract version of `scala.Option`.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait OptionSig {
  type Option[+_]
  type Some[+A] <: Option[A]
  type None <: Option[Nothing]
}

abstract class OptionOps[Sig <: OptionSig] extends Extractors[Sig] {
  def some[A](x: A): Sig#Some[A]
  def none: Sig#None
  def fold[A, B](opt: Sig#Option[A])(ifNone: => B, ifSome: A => B): B
}
```

I want to be able to use pattern matching on `Sig#Option[A]` so `Extractors` looks like that:

```
trait Extractors[Sig <: OptionSig] { self: OptionOps[Sig] =>

  object Some {
    def unapply[A](opt: Sig#Option[A]): scala.Option[A] =
      fold(opt)(scala.None, a => scala.Some(a))
  }

  object None {
    def unapply[A](opt: Sig#Option[A]): Option[Unit] =
      fold(opt)(scala.Some(()), _ => scala.None)
  }

}
```

Now I can write this program:

```
class Program[Sig <: OptionSig](implicit ops: OptionOps[Sig]) extends App {

  import ops._

  val opt: Sig#Option[Int] = some(42)

  opt match {
    case None(_)  => sys.error("")
    case Some(42) => println("yay")
    case Some(_)  => sys.error("")
  }

}
```

And I can test it with this implementation.

```
trait ScalaOption extends OptionSig {

  type Option[+A] = scala.Option[A]
  type Some[+A]   = scala.Some[A]
  type None       = scala.None.type

}

object ScalaOption {

  implicit object ops extends OptionOps[ScalaOption] {

    def some[A](x: A): ScalaOption#Some[A] = scala.Some(x)

    val none: ScalaOption#None = scala.None

    def fold[A, B](opt: ScalaOption#Option[A])(ifNone: => B, ifSome: A => B): B =
      opt match {
        case scala.None    => ifNone
        case scala.Some(x) => ifSome(x)
      }

  }

}

object Main extends Program[ScalaOption]
```

It looks like it works but there is one annoying thing I cannot figure out.

With, `scala.Option`, the type of `s` in `Option(42) match { case s @ Some(42) => s }` is `Some[Int]`. But with my snippet above, it is `Sig#Option[Int]` and I would like to make it `Sig#Some[Int]` instead.

So I tried the following to be closer to what scalac generates for its case classes:

```
trait Extractors[Sig <: OptionSig] { self: OptionOps[Sig] =>

  object Some {
    def unapply[A](s: Sig#Some[A]): scala.Option[A] =
      fold(s)(scala.None, a => scala.Some(a))
  }

  object None {
    def unapply(n: Sig#None): Option[Unit] =
      fold(n)(scala.Some(()), (_: Any) => scala.None)
  }

}
```

But now I get warnings like the following:

```
[warn] Main.scala:78: abstract type pattern Sig#None is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case None(_)  => sys.error("")
```

I am not sure why this is happening as `Sig#None` is a subtype of `Sig#Option[Int]` and this is *known at compile time*.

Also the runtime is still ok, but the inferred type is still not the one I was expecting.

So the questions are

- why is type erasure mentioned here despite the subtyping information?
- how to get `Sig#Option[Int]` for `s` in `(some(42): Sig#Option[Int]) match { case s @ Some(42) => s }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do what you want. The problem is that it is not enough that scalac know that `Sig#None <: Sig#Option[A]`, it must be able to verify that the value it is passing to `unapply` is, in fact, `Sig#None`. This works for `scala.Option`, because the compiler can generate an `instanceof` check to verify that a type is actually a `Some` or a `None` before passing it to the `unapply` method. If it fails the check, it *skips* that pattern (and `unapply` is never called).

In your case, since scalac only knows that `opt` is a `Sig#Option[Int]`, it cannot do anything to guarantee that the value is actually a `Some` or `None` before passing it along to `unapply`.

So what does it do? *It passes the value along anyways!* What does this mean? Well, let's modify your extractors a bit:

```
trait Extractors[Sig <: OptionSig] { self: OptionOps[Sig] =>
  object Some {
    def unapply[A](s: Sig#Some[A]): scala.Option[A] =
      fold(s)(scala.None, a => scala.Some(a))
  }

  object None {
    def unapply(n: Sig#None): Option[Unit] =
      scala.Some(())
  }
}
```

All we've done is stopped using `fold` in the `None` case. Since we *know* the argument must be a `Sig#None`, why even bother calling `fold`, right? I mean, we wouldn't expect a `Sig#Some` to be passed here, right?

When we run this example, you'll hit a `RuntimeException`, because our very first pattern match *succeeds* and calls `???`. In the case of `scala.Option`, the pattern would fail because it's guarded by a generated `instanceof` check.

I've gisted another example that shows another danger, where we add a small constraint to `Sig#Some`, which let's us avoid the `fold` in the `Some` case too: https://gist.github.com/tixxit/ab99b741d3f5d2668b91

Anyways, your specific case is technically safe. We know that you used `fold` and so it is safe to use with an `Sig#Option`. The problem is that `scalac` doesn't know that.

Comment: Excellent answer. Do you know of an easy way to see how the pattern matching gets compiled? Or any bits of documentation/specification explaining how it gets compiled?

Comment: @betehess You can use :javap in the REPL (doesn't work in 2.10). You can see an example session here (see line 103 for instanceof): https://gist.github.com/tixxit/cacceaff6b25bafb2816